# How to fix "File is not a zip file"

Tags: django, excel, openpyxl

I am trying to upload some data representing information about products.
The first row of my excel file represents the id of the product.
The data in the column cells (begin from the 2nd row and then) represent  serial numbers.

I can not upload successfully my .xls file , taking back the error File is not a zip file.

my view

```
def excel_view(request):
    if "GET" == request.method:
        return render(request, 'excel/excel_form.html', {})
    else:
        excel_file = request.FILES["excel_file"]

        # you may put validations here to check extension or file size

        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(excel_file)
        sheet_obj = wb.active 

        # getting a particular sheet by name out of many sheets
        worksheet = wb["Sheet1"]
        # print(worksheet)

        excel_data = list()
        # iterating over the rows and
        # getting value from each cell in row

        #flag=0
        header_list=[] #list to store drug index
        input_dict={} #dict to store serial numbers per drug
        i = 0 #index of columns
        j = 0 #index of rows
        for row in worksheet.iter_rows():
             ....
```

my template

```
       <title>
            Excel file upload and processing
        </title>
    <body style="margin-top: 30px;margin-left: 30px;">

      <h1>Excel file upload and processing</h1>
        <form action="{% url 'excel_functionality' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="file"
                   title="Upload excel file"
                   name="excel_file"
                   style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px;"
                   required="required">
            <p>
            <input type="submit"
                   value="Upload"
                   style="border: 1px solid green; padding:5px; border-radius: 2px; cursor: pointer;">
        </form>
```

my Traceback

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://example/excel/

Django Version: 1.11.16
Python Version: 2.7.12
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'bootstrap3',
 'bootstrap_themes',
 'intranet',
 'crispy_forms',
 'fm',
 'dal',
 'dal_select2',
 'django_crontab',
 'django_tables2',
 'django_filters']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/var/www/vhosts/intranet.health-nutrition.gr/health_nutrition/intranet/views.py" in excel_view
  3355.         wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(excel_file)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py" in load_workbook
  174.     archive = _validate_archive(filename)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py" in _validate_archive
  124.         archive = ZipFile(f, 'r', ZIP_DEFLATED)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py" in __init__
  770.                 self._RealGetContents()

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/zipfile.py" in _RealGetContents
  811.             raise BadZipfile, "File is not a zip file"

Exception Type: BadZipfile at /excel/
Exception Value: File is not a zip file
```

Why this happened, any idea?

Comment: `.xls` files are not zip archives, though `.xlsx` are.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad you are right. Finally found the solution, I uploaded my file as .xlsx